# F# What is the value of x and type?

Tags: f#

```
let x = List.map (sum x -> x + 1) [10; 20; 30]
```

I am having trouble understanding what the value of variable type of x will be.

Comment: The value of x will be the result of the evaluation of the expression on the right-hand side of the equals sign.

Comment: As an aside, I can't get your line of code to compile.  It fails in two different online F# interpreters with the error "Unexpected symbol - > in expression."  Read "How to create a [mcve]" for further guidance.

Comment: See also [Understanding Map and Apply](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/elevated-world/).

Comment: your code doesnt make sense - i assume fun x -> x+ 1...in which case this maps the values of the list to a new list adding 1 to each member

Answer (score 2):

First, i guess you want `fun` not `sum`

```
let x = List.map (fun x -> x + 1) [10; 20; 30]
```

Next,
`x` is the result of the function `List.map`. `List.map` returns a new list by applying the lambda function (provided as the first argument) applied to every argument of the list (provided by the second argument).

Technically, every element of the list is increased by one element. So you get as a result.

```
[11; 21; 31]
```

You can think of `List.map` as doing

```
let x = [
    (fun x -> x + 1) 10
    (fun x -> x + 1) 20
    (fun x -> x + 1) 30
]
```

Still F#, but in the logic of C# or a more imperative language, it compares to the following code.

```
let ys = [10;20;30]

let x =
    let xs = ResizeArray()
    for g in ys do
        let tmp = g + 1
        xs.Add tmp
    List.ofSeq xs

printfn "%A" x // [11;21;31]
```